# Improving concurrency in a multithreading example

Tags: java, multithreading

Locking mechanism - Each method runs a Queue for tracking in-process keys being proceeding for that method.

```
    private final static Object LOCK = new Object();
    private final static Set<String> busy1Records = new HashSet<String>();
    private final static Set<String> busy2Records = new HashSet<String>();

    public void waitToWorkOn(int i, String key) {
        synchronized(LOCK) {

          switch(i) {
            case 1 : while (busy1Records.contains(key)) {
                        LOCK.wait(); //go to sleep
                     }
                     busy1Records.add(key);  
                     break;
            case 2 : while (busy2Records.contains(key)) {
                     LOCK.wait(); //go to sleep
                     }
                     busy2Records.add(key);  
                     break;
          }//end switch

       } // end sychronized                    
    }


    public void doneWith(int i, String key) {
        synchronized(LOCK) {

        switch(i) { 

          case 1:
              busy1Records.remove(key);
              LOCK.notifyAll(); 
              break;
          case 2:
              busy2Records.remove(key);
              LOCK.notifyAll(); 
              break;

        }
```

To use these Sets , there are these methods in that class.

```
private void method1(String key) {

try {

waitToWorkOn(1,key);
// Do stuffs here for key   

}catch(Exception e)  {..}
finally {
doneWith(1,key);
}

}

private void method2(String key) {

try {

waitToWorkOn(2,key);    
// Do stuffs here for key

}catch(Exception e)  {..}
finally {
doneWith(2,key);
}

}
```

Consider there are 3 Threads [ Each thread works on a new instance of this class]

```
T1 - key = X
T2 - key = X
T3 - key = Z
```

So when T1 is in method1, it acquires the LOCK and adds key to its queue for method1 and releases the LOCK. But it has not yet called doneWith method and then another Thread T2 tries to insert same entity X. So it acquires LOCK in waitToWorkON and since it finds X already in Queue1 , so it has to wait inside. Then a Thread T3 comes that has to call method1 on third entity Z which is independent of X. But it won't be able to acquire LOCK since T2 is waiting and holds the LOCK.

How can I let T3 to proceed with method1 for Z without waiting for T2 waiting on X there ?
T1 still has not released X from Queue.

Comment: It's very confusing for me. Can you tell me simply what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want that a thread should wait for another thread only when whey are procesing same key. Else they should run concurrently. T2 waits for T1 and that follows this rule but T3 waits for T2 as well .. I need to avoid this 2nd situation as they work on different keys.

Comment: Why you lock both sets together?

Comment: Actually I needed that if one thread is processing a key in method1 , then it should not lock another thread processing method2 even though using same key. So I created separate Sets for each methods so that each method checks busy records for Set that belongs to only that method.

Comment: @Hamlet , I will state it even more clearly - Main problem is LOCK.wait() statement inside synchronized(LOCK) block. If a thread is waiting , then can another Thread still acquire LOCK inside waitToWorkon() ?  If it can , then it solves my problem ..

Comment: @fortm `LOCK.wait()` releases the lock, which is reacquired when `wait` returns. So yes, if thread 1 is waiting, thread 2 can enter the synchronized block.

Comment: Ok, i understand what you want to achieve. Yes, when lock calls wait, it releases lock and thread goes to wait queue until it will be signaled. After that the thread moves to ready queue and **WAITs** to reacquire the lock.

Comment: OK, this is good then. That was some basic mistake I was doing .. Actually , I have reached as far in its implementaion by asking question in StackOverflow only .. SO, thanks to you all :) I wonder, however if using ConcurrentLinkedQueue would have simplified my code as here I have as many as 10 sets for prevent locking in 10 such methods ..

Comment: having 10 methods to work with 10 sets is silly. Put all sets in an array and add parameter - index of the set to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Hamlet and @assylias for answers

> @fortm LOCK.wait() releases the lock, which is reacquired when wait returns. So yes, if thread 1 is waiting, thread 2 can enter the synchronized block. – assylias 21 mins ago 
>   1  up voted
>
> Ok, i understand what you want to achieve. Yes, when lock calls wait,
>   it releases lock and thread goes to wait queue until it will be
>   signaled. After that the thread moves to ready queue and WAITs to
>   reacquire the lock. – Hamlet Hakobyan 2 mins ago